# Converting a String to hex for use as canvas paint color Java

Tags: java, colors, hex, int

```
void changeColor(int a, int r, int g, int b){
    String hex = + Integer.toHexString(a) + Integer.toHexString(r) +
                   Integer.toHexString(g) + Integer.toHexString(b);

    int color = hex //Obviously this is a type mismatch, but how do I do this?

    mpaint.setColor(color);
}
```

Obviously this is a type mismatch, but how do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

If you need a Color variable, you can use the Color contructor (but have to change the range to 0.0-1.0)

`Color(float r, float g, float b, float a)`

But if you need an `int` in the end, you have to use bitshifts (this is an example, you have to know how the color components need to be ordered) :

`int color = (r << 24) | (g << 16) | (b << 8) | a;`

Comment: Actually I found out that the Android SDK for the paint object has a built in color setter in the same format. mpaint.setARGB(a, r, g, b);